# File uploading in jQuery and inject the FileData from JS to Bean class

Tags: jquery, html, jsf

I am trying to upload file using jQuery and Bean. 
I can able to upload a file but can't able to get it in the Bean class.

Please help me to solve this. please refer my code.

JavaScript code

```
    var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var file = files[0];

        if (files && file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
                var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result; 
                var imgsrc = btoa(binaryString);
                $("input:text").val(imgsrc);
            };

            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }
    };

    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        document.getElementById('filePicker').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }
```

HTML

```
 <div>
    <input type="file" onchange="uploadFile()" />
    <p:inputText id="newT" value="#{testBean.fileDemo}"  ></p:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="click" action="#{testBean.submit}" ></h:commandButton>
</div>
```

Bean class

```
    @Service
    @Scope("session")
    class TestBean {

        String a;
        Byte[] fileArray

        public void submit(){
            println "Bye arraya is  "+fileArray;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why trying it the hard way while you can just use `<p:fileUpload>` or `<h:inputFile>`? If you want to do it the "plain vanilla" way, use a servlet, not a backing bean. Otherwise you have to manually write a lot of code which basically performs the same task as what those JSF components already autogenerate for you. Do you understand why JSF exist?

Comment: I tried <p:fileUpload> but it has some issues while choosing file and no error message is displayed for the wrong selection other than mentioned allowedTypes